# How to remove a parent theme template from Quick Edit?

Tags: page-template, child-theme, parent-theme, quick-edit

I was looking for a way to hide the parent theme's templates and found this answer which works perfectly to remove the parent templates from the pages edit screen - [How to *remove* a parent theme page template from a child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-to-remove-a-parent-theme-page-template-from-a-child-theme).

I don't want the parent templates that I've removed to show anywhere in admin, however they still appear in the dropdown box labeled "Template" on WP Admin > Pages > All Pages in the "QUICK EDIT" section.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Answer remade. The original was a wild idea...

The solution is the same as the one posted by Rarst in the question linked
[How to *remove* a parent theme page template from a child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13671/12615)

Difference being the `admin_head` hook.
And a check for only running in `edit-page` and not in `edit-post` or `edit-custom_post_type`, as all these cases are fired by `admin_head-edit.php`.

The parent is "Twenty Eleven" and the child is called "Twenty Twelve".

```
add_action('admin_head-edit.php','wpse_54054_remove_template');

function wpse_54054_remove_template() 
{   
    global $wp_themes,$current_screen;

    if('edit-page' != $current_screen->id)
        return;

    get_themes();

    $templates = &$wp_themes['Twenty Twelve']['Template Files'];

    $template1 = trailingslashit( TEMPLATEPATH ).'showcase.php';
    $template2 = trailingslashit( TEMPLATEPATH ).'sidebar-page.php';

    $key1 = array_search($template1, $templates);
    $key2 = array_search($template2, $templates);

    unset( $templates[$key1], $templates[$key2] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @brasofilo.  Looks like I may need to go for an easier solution:  Override the parent theme's templates.  I wanted to show only the child theme's templates for naming reasons.  That is, instead of template-2, template-3, etc. I wanted to use more descriptive names customized to the website.

Comment: @user16689 - geeee... I'm always thinking on brute force jQuery solutions... sorry... amending the answer in a sec...

Comment: Has anyone tested this answer on 3.4+? I'm not getting it to working, and from poking around a bit, it seems that WordPress changes the way themes were handled a lot. I think the templates are now private and in an object, breaking the above script. And sadly, my PHP skillz leave me stuck at that observation.