# How do I limit the status options for bulk/quick edit to only Published and Draft?

Tags: bulk, quick-edit, wp-list-table, post-status

For my custom post type, I only want to have "Published" and "Draft" as the available options in the bulk edit and quick edit screens, i.e.

[image: screenshot]

I tried hooking on to the filter `quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args` but it doesn't seem to get fired. I inserted a `wp_die()` in my callback but the admin screen lists all posts like nothing changed. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, so i found the `wp_die()` IS getting fired, but it doesn't stop the whole page from displaying -- only the drop-down menu. just clarifying. thanks, y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering [this Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/13671/12615), came to a jQuery solution to Ana Ban's one.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_56551_script_enqueuer' );

function wpse_56551_script_enqueuer() 
{
    global $current_screen;

    /**
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
       /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=cpt  == gallery in this example
     */
    if( 'edit-gallery' == $current_screen->id ) 
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">         
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $("a.editinline").live("click", function () {
                var ilc_qe_id = inlineEditPost.getId(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#edit-'+ilc_qe_id+' select[name="_status"] option[value="pending"]').remove();  
                        $('#edit-'+ilc_qe_id+' select[name="_status"] option[value="private"]').remove();  
                    }, 100);
            });

            $('#doaction, #doaction2').live("click", function () {
                setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#bulk-edit select[name="_status"] option[value="pending"]').remove();  
                        $('#bulk-edit select[name="_status"] option[value="private"]').remove();  
                    }, 100);
            });       
        });    
        </script>
    <?php
    }

    /**
       /wp-admin/post.php?post=21&action=edit
     */
    if( 'gallery' == $current_screen->id ) 
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $('#post_status option[value="pending"]').remove();
            $('#post_status option[value="private"]').remove();
        });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

**[Original Answer]**

> Searching for this filter in `/wp-admin/`, we find it located at
>   `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`. And we see that it
>   deals with the hierarchy of posts, not with the status...
>
> Further down in this file we find the status group, but it don't have
>   any filter, *so I suspect* there won't be a hooked solution...
>
> ```
> // starting at line 950
> <div class="inline-edit-group">
> <label class="inline-edit-status alignleft">
>   <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Status' ); ?></span>
>   <select name="_status">
> <?php if ( $bulk ) : ?>
>       <option value="-1"><?php _e( '&mdash; No Change &mdash;' ); ?></option>
> <?php endif; // $bulk ?>
>   <?php if ( $can_publish ) : // Contributors only get "Unpublished" and "Pending Review" ?>
>       <option value="publish"><?php _e( 'Published' ); ?></option>
>       <option value="future"><?php _e( 'Scheduled' ); ?></option>
> <?php if ( $bulk ) : ?>
>       <option value="private"><?php _e( 'Private' ) ?></option>
> <?php endif; // $bulk ?>
>   <?php endif; ?>
>       <option value="pending"><?php _e( 'Pending Review' ); ?></option>
>       <option value="draft"><?php _e( 'Draft' ); ?></option>
>   </select>
> </label>
> ```

Comment: so frustrating. had to settle for a core edit. thanks for validating my suspicion that this couldn't be hooked for now. :D

Comment: @AnaBan : Edited the Answer and posted a jQuery workaround ;)